# table name as variable in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(a integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
begin

     for row in
                     Select id  from table_a    where quantity=1
    loop
        do something
    end loop

end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I need to change this function to take another parameter which tells if to use `table_a` or `table_b`.

when `whichtouse=1` I need to use `table_a`.

when `whichtouse=2` I need to use `table_b`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(a integer,whichtouse integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
begin

     for row in
                     Select id  from ??? where quantity=1
    loop
        do something
    end loop

end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

How can I determin which table to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [dynamic SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(a integer, whichtouse integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
declare
  l_sql text;
  l_rec record;
begin
  if whichtouse = 1 then
    l_sql := format('select id from %I where qantity=1', 'table_a');
  else 
    l_sql := format('select id from %I where qantity=1', 'table_b');
  end if;

   for l_rec in execute l_sql
   loop
      -- do something
   end loop;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Answer (score 2):

Using temporary table to get data from table based on condition.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(a integer,whichtouse integer)
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    rec   record;
begin


    drop  table if exists temp_data;
    if whichtouse=1
    then 
        create temporary table temp_data as
        Select id  from table_a    where quantity=1;
    else
        create temporary table temp_data as
        Select id  from table_b    where quantity=1;
    end if;

    for rec in Select id  from temp_data 
    loop
        -- do something here
    end loop;

end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: Creating a temporary table is not necessary